# Código de C, me da varios warning en el strcpy

Tags: c, str

soy estudiante de DAM y estoy haciendo una práctica de programación para clase. Me he quedado atascada sobre todo con el strcpy (os pongo el código abajo), aunque no sé si hay más errores. El ejercicio es sobre introducir datos sobre películas y series en un fichero. No está terminado, pero me he atascado ahí porque no compila, me salen varios warning (aparentemente relativos a los argumentos). Ojalá me podáis ayudar, muchas gracias.

Perdón, no he especificado bien a qué warning me refería.
Los dos que más me aparecen son: "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function strcpy" y "passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integrer without a cast". No entiendo qué significan.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ficha{
    char nombre [25];
    char tipo [25];
    int duracion;
    char plataforma [25];
    int anio;
};
 
// Declaración de funciones.
void pideDatosChar (char* pregunta, char* texto);

main (){
    FILE *fichero;
    
    struct ficha fichas [100];
    struct ficha temporal [100];
    
    char nombreFichas [25];
    char tipoFichas [25];   
    int duracionFichas;
    char plataformaFichas [25];
    int anioFichas;
    
    int contador = 0;
    int contadorfila = 0;
    int fila;
    
    int opcion;
    int i;

    fichero = fopen("PeliculasYSeries.txt", "a");
    
    void volcardatos();
    void pideDatos();
    
    do{
        menu(); 
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
            pideDatos ("Nombre: ", nombreFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",nombreFichas);
            pideDatos ("Tipo: ", tipoFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",tipoFichas);
            pideDatos ("Duracion: ", duracionFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",duracionFichas);
            pideDatos("Plataforma: ", plataformaFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",plataformaFichas);
            pideDatos ("Año: ", anioFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",anioFichas);
            printf ("------------------------------\n");
            
            fichero = fopen ("SeriesyPeliculas.txt", "a");
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",tipoFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%d\n",duracionFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%s\n",plataformaFichas);
            fprintf(fichero,"%d\n",anioFichas);
            contador++;
            
            strcpy (fichas[contador].nombre, nombreFichas); 
            strcpy (fichas[contador].tipo, tipoFichas);
            strcpy (fichas[contador].duracion, duracionFichas);
            strcpy (fichas[contador].plataforma, plataformaFichas); 
            strcpy (fichas[contador].anio, anioFichas);
            
        
            break;
            }
        
    }while (opcion != 0);
    
        while ((fgets (fila, 25, fichero)) != NULL){
            if (contadorfila%6 == 0){
                strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].nombre, fila);
            }else if (contadorfila%6 == 1){
                strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].tipo, fila);
            }else if (contadorfila%6 == 2){
                strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].duracion, fila);
            }else if (contadorfila&6 == 3){
                strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].plataforma, fila);
            }else if (contadorfila&6 == 4){
                strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].anio, fila);
            }
            

        
    fclose(fichero);
    }   
}
```

He mirado el código muchas veces y no entiendo qué ocurre. Varios compañeros lo han mirado también y han toqueteado y tampoco saben por qué salen tantísimos warning con el strcpy, supongo que no estamos mirando bien algo.

Comment: Estaría bien que incluyas las advertencias que quieres resolver en la pregunta. En el compilador me aparecen más de 20 y no creo que quieras ayuda con todos.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. He especificado qué dos advertencias son las que más problemas me dan.

Comment: c no es lo mismo que c++ por favor especifica el lenguaje correctamente...

Comment: Lo he redactado rápido, siento la confusión.

Comment: No entiendo, pideDato es una funcion que no recive parametro, pero tu le pasa dos, y a parte de eso es solo un prototipo no una funcion, lo que hace que el linker te genere error y no te compilara nada

Comment: Te recomiendo que incluyas stdlib.h y cambies un poco la funcion de pedir datos(Pero ponlo fuera de main para que no te genere ningun warning: void pideDatos(const char* MSG,char dato_rellenar[25]){
    printf(MSG);/*Mostramos el nombre del dato que queremos pedir*/
    fgets(dato_rellenar,25,stdin);/*Pedimos el dato.*/
}

Comment: Tambien hay veces que quieres que strcpy concatene una cadena y en un entero, algo que el compilador no te va a dejar: strcpy (fichas[contadorfila].anio, fila); /*Anio no es un char[25]; sino que es un entero(int), Por lo que si el compilador te dejara, cuando la applicacion se ejecute y llegue a esa linea el programa se cerrará. Porque intentaria acceder a un espacio de memoria que probablemente no sea de ella*/

Comment: A y se me olvido decirte, te falta incluir string.h(#include <string,h>) donde esta la funcion strcpy;) .

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, me ha dejado de dar varias advertencias siguiendo lo que me has dicho, a ver si consigo solucionar el resto :)

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente advertencia marca que hay llamadas a una función sin haberla declarado:

```
.code.tio.c:63:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strcpy (fichas[contador].nombre, nombreFichas);
```

En C debes decirle al compilador que tus funciones (y variables también) existen **antes** de usarlas. Puede ser en cualquier parte del código siempre y cuando esté **antes**. Eso se hace mediante una declaración y los el objetivo de los archivos **.h** ese contener declaraciones. Por ese motivo es que los `#include` suelen ir al inicio del archivo.

Supón que tienes la función `sumar`. Su declaración se vería así:

```
void sumar(int a, int b);
```

Desde C99 la declaración de [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) es la siguiente y puedes escribirla manualmente:

```
char *strcpy( char *restrict dest, const char *restrict src );
```

O en su lugar, escribir `#include <string.h>` al comienzo del archivo.

---

La siguiente advertencia:

```
.code.tio.c:65:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         strcpy (fichas[contador].duracion, duracionFichas);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
.code.tio.c:65:48: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         strcpy (fichas[contador].duracion, duracionFichas);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Significa que está ocurriendo una conversión implícita de `int` a un puntero (`char*` en este caso). No es algo que normalmente harías entonces el compilador te avisa para asegurarse de que esa sea tu intención. Si es tu caso, debes ser explícita respecto a la conversión y las advertencias desaparecerán.

Un [type cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) se realiza escribiendo antes de la variable o el valor, entre paréntesis, el tipo al que quieres convertir. En las advertencias de ejemplo sería así:

```
strcpy ((char*)fichas[contador].duracion, (const char*)duracionFichas);
```

---

Al ver la siguiente estructura y las líneas de la advertencia anterior:

```
struct ficha{
    char nombre [25];
    char tipo [25];
    int duracion;
    char plataforma [25];
    int anio;
};
```

Pienso que olvidaste que `duracion` y `anio` son `int`. Porque `strcpy` copia una cadena de un `char *` (o `char[]` puesto que hay una conversión implícita de arreglos a punteros) a otro. No está pensado para números.

En lugar de:

```
strcpy (fichas[contador].duracion, duracionFichas);
strcpy (fichas[contador].anio, anioFichas);
```

Simplemente deberías asignar el valor de `duracionFichas` y `anioFichas` a sus contrapartes en la estructura. Así:

```
fichas[contador].duracion = duracionFichas;
fichas[contador].anio = anioFichas;
```

---

Nuevamente, antes en el código pareces confundirte con los tipos. Porque `duracionFichas` y `anioFichas` son enteros, sin embargo los usas como si fueran `char *`:

```
pideDatos ("Duracion: ", duracionFichas);
fprintf(fichero,"%s\n", duracionFichas);
pideDatos ("Año: ", anioFichas);
fprintf(fichero,"%s\n", anioFichas);
```

Sugiero que en lugar de una sola función `pideDatos` tengas varias especializadas según el caso. De lo contrario tienes que realizar una conversión de texto a número. Por ejemplo, `pideEntero`, `pideFloat`, `pideCadena`, `pideCaracter`:

```
char pideCaracter(char* mensaje){
    ...
}
int pideEntero(char* mensaje){
    ...
}
float pideFloat(char* mensaje){
    ...
}
// En este caso necesitarás recibir un puntero a donde quieras que se guarde la cadena.
// Sino tienes que reservar memoria.
void pideCadena(char* mensaje, char* buffer){
    ...
}
```

---

Por cierto:

- Supongo que las funciones `pideDatos`, `volcarDatos` y otras no se ven en el fragmento pero sí están en tu código original.
- A la función `main` le falta el tipo de retorno (`int`).
- `fila` es una variable de tipo `int`. Como primer parámetro de la función `fgets` deberías pasar un `char*` en su lugar. Por eso obtienes una advertencia.
- Una situación similar a la del punto anterior sucede con el uso de `strcpy` dentro del if.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Sin embargo, sigue dándome warning en el fgets y los strcpy que tiene debajo. Es el mismo warning una y otra vez... he probado lo que me has dicho pero ahí, haga lo que haga, no consigo que funcione.

Comment: @claudia ya lo edité. Las advertencias que quedan son parecidas a las que ya expliqué. Ten cuidado con los tipos de las variables y las funciones que usas. También recuerda hacer las conversiones que sean necesarias. No puedes convertir de `int` a un string (`char*`) directamente. Necesitas usar alguna función como las de [`stdlib.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi). Si no entiendes como funciona C, una respuesta sería demasiado larga. Considera pedirle a tu profesor que te explique, ver algún tutorial o ir al [chat] quizá alguien te explique.

Comment: vale, lo he vuelto a mirar ahora con más calma y y ya he visto los errores, muchas gracias.